# How to parse "2021.147.17.33.45" using Howard Hinnant's date library (or the equivalent C++20 STL functionalities)

Tags: c++, datetime, parsing, c++20

I've got a string representing a date in the format `<year>.<day-of-the-year>.<hours>.<minutes>.<seconds>`.

Example: `2021.147.17.33.45` is the 27th of May 2021, with time 17:33:45.

How to parse this formatted time string into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) or the equivalent [C++20 functionalities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse)?

I've tried with the following, with no result: the output `time_point` is always zero.

```
auto toTimePoint(const std::string& val)
{
    std::istringstream ss(val);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    std::chrono::from_stream(ss, "%Y.%j.%H.%M.%S", tp)
    return tp;
}
```

EDIT: This code fails using Visual Studio v16.10 with `\std:c++latest`, but works correctly using Howard Hinnant's date library (see the comment of T.C. below). I've opened a new [issue](http://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1938) on the Microsoft STL GitHub repository.

Comment: Works for me with date: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EfxeG4YPj

Comment: @T.C. Wow! A URL in an `#include`... (I've never seen before.)

Comment: @Scheff https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516521/12861639 it says to be a godbolt feature

Comment: Some context: I have some experience with Howard Hinnant's date library, but when starting a new project I decided to use the allegedly equivalent C++20, shipped with Visual Studio v16.10. The equivalence must therefore be not so strict. Unfortunately there is no way to test the behaviour of VS v16.10 online to show you my point...

Comment: I've opened a new issue on the Microsoft STL GitHub repository: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1938